# How do you add different port on SshClient?

Tags: c#, ssh

I am trying to connect using SshClient (Renci library) but I don't find a way to add a different port while connecting. It's using the default 22 port:

Code sample:

```
using (var client = new SshClient(IP, username, password)) { }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw that SshClient supports ports. You can write below:

```
using (var client = new SshClient(IP, port, username, password)) { }
```